# Why are my components unconnected in the middle of the breadboard?

Tags: integrated-circuit, breadboard

I have this breadboard:

[image]

And I need my Integrated Circuit to be connected exactly like this (Don't pay any attention to the wires. Let's focus on the IC in the middle of the breadboard itself):

[image]

However, when I connected the power, it didn't work. Then I found out that the IC was pushed up from the breadboard. I tried to push it down and it worked, but when I released my fingers, it stopped working again. **That was like the legs of the IC was not long enough to be buried deeply into the breadboard. I had problems with not only the IC but the pushbutton as well.**

Did anybody face that kind of problem like me? Please show me the trick to bury the components deeper in the middle of the breadboard. Thank you.

Comment: Do you realize that the individual blue and red lines on the top and bottom of the breadboard are not connected together ?

Comment: @jp314 -- he's having a different problem altogether

Comment: Feel at the bottom side of the board if all springs are pushed well into the board.

Comment: REALLY nice pictures. More people who ask questions here should take pictures as high-quality as yours, sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a brand new breadboard, it is possible that the contact tines (the contacts within the breadboard sockets) have a nominal opening that is *smaller* than the size of the IC pins; this will 'push' the IC back out of the breadboard sockets.

I have seen this (admittedly many years ago), and a piece of non-stranded wire judiciously used can open the contact a bit so the breadboard will not push the IC back out. Be careful so as not to actually damage the contact; just open it up a bit.

Comment: Note that most breadboards can be disassembled, look for screws on the reverse side. So if bending the tines goes a little too far and it refuses to seat smaller leads, it usually is correctable by disassembly and gently closing the pins some. (Needle-nose pliers and a very steady hand.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try my best to open up the contact. You know, it was annoying. Every time I put my IC or pushbutton or everything else in the middle of the breadboard, like a bridge from one half to another half, the breadboard pushes them up. Now I will fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Normally, these breadboards are built exactly for what you're trying to do. And normally, it works, because there aren't many different lengths of pins on ICs.

If more force doesn't help (i.e. your IC just can't be pushed in further), I'm afraid all you could try is use a IC socket; but to be honest, that would sound like a lot of trouble considering the job of holding and connecting your IC is exactly what you use your breadboard for.

Considering that you had problems with a button, too, I'd say that stranger things have happened than breadboards with varying build quality :(

Comment: If it's a new breadboard I'd return it and try a different vendor/brand - "varying build quality" is sophisticated speech for something less polite that might apply.

Answer (score 2):

One of my breadboards acts this way. I hated it and decided to sacrifice it to make [This Breadboard Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ME2wgVFYgIs).

Also, YES: longer leaded parts will fit into that breadboard. But you shouldn't need to purchase specific ICs to fit into a breadboard. You just need a better breadboard.

Spend eight bucks and get a new one. Most breadboards don't exhibit the bad behavior you describe.

Cheers!